# How to check if ad banner is loaded before hiding it?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I am using a Revmob banner in one of my apps, and when the user exits that screen, the banner is set to hidden.

This works perfectly, however, IF the banner is not visible, perhaps it did not load that time, or they have switched screens quickly, then the app will crash with a

```
message sent to deallocated instance
```

Error.

That makes sense of course as there is nothing to deallocate/hide, so my question is, how can I check if the banner is loaded, so that it only hides it, if it is visible;

The code when exiting the screen is;

```
-(void)onExit {


    [super onExit];

    [[RevMobAds session] hideBanner];

}
```

The code to call the banner is

```
[super onEnter];

        [[RevMobAds session] showBanner];
```

I wondered if there is something like this I could use to maybe check?

```
if ([RevMobAds session].bannerisVisible == YES)
{
    [[RevMobAds session] hideBanner];
}else{

}
```

Comment: In case nobody gives the answer (which is likely), they have Support button at the bottom-right corner.

Comment: I tested here and this error don't happen with SDK version 5.4.0 are you using an old version? Did you tried to get in contact with they?

Comment: I use 5.4.0 also, I did contact but waiting their reply.
It is only a problem if no banner is displayed BEFORE the user clicks to go out of the screen, although, if you turn mobile data off (no wifi etc) then it does not crash, even though no adverts show because of data turned off... So it's quite odd really?